# Windows Authentication Docker

Tags: authentication, docker, .net-core

I am new to Docker and am currently trying to "convert" one of our applications to .NET Core to get it work inside a docker container.

However, I am struggling to get the windows authentication to work.
I need to read the windows username from the user inside the controller.

When calling

```
var userName = this.User.Identity.Name;
```

the result is empty.

My launchSettings.json looks as following:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57078/",
  "sslPort": 0
}
  },
  "profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"Feedback.WebApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57079/"
}
}
}
```

I already tried configuring something in the Program.cs and Startup.cs but that did not help either.

When I add

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

to the Startup.cs I get following error message:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there         was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+    <ChallengeAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you come up with a solution?